# "yet" meaning "nonetheless|nevertheless" with the clause-positional freedom of "nonetheless|nevertheless" in contemporary spoken English, Br vs Am

Tags: conjunctions

I was talking with a friend about a book she was reading (British author, 1930s) whose opening sentence was structured along the following lines (the emphasis of my analogue is on the meaning and position of **yet**):

> No professional chef, he yet knew the differences between cooking *sous vide* and  *alla InstaPot*.

The word "yet" is being used there as a synonym for "nonetheless|nevertheless". In *spoken* American English (my own tongue) the word "yet" when it's a synonym for either of those words does not enjoy the freedom-of-position that they enjoy and I think the same is true for written American English (in utilitarian prose, poetry, and prose literature).

> Nonetheless|nevertheless he said OK.
>
> He nonetheless|nevertheless said OK.
>
> He said nonetheless|nevertheless OK.
>
> He said OK nonetheless|nevertheless.

I haven't used any commas there, though normally they would be used.

She cited the King James Bible as example of this meaning and syntactic position in the clause, along with some later attestations. But I doubt it is used in current spoken British English any more than it is  in current spoken American English, which is not at all. I think the author was using a deliberate syntactic archaism. Any opinions and evidence to the contrary?

Comment: I'd agree it is not current in that position in either variety of English. **More usual would be**: No professional chef, **yet he knew** the differences between cooking sous vide and alla InstaPot.

Comment: Yet as a conjunction means ‘but’ or ‘nevertheless’. We use it to show contrast. It often occurs after and:

*So many questions and yet so few answers.

It felt strange and yet so wonderful to ski in the summer!* (Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: ***Yet for emphasis*** 

We use yet for emphasis, with a meaning similar to ‘even’, especially before more, another and again:

*The cook arrived with yet another plate of cake.

The printer’s broken down yet again! (It has broken down many times before.)* (Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: @user 66974 : your remarks are not relevant.